# New project compile error (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

Whe i create a new android studio project (version 0.3.5) and try to run it, it results in an error, which i can not seem to solve (also i am very new to android programming). The error is the following:

> Gradle: Execution failed for task ':HelloWorld:packageDebug'.
>
> > Could not call IncrementalTask.taskAction() on task ':HelloWorld:packageDebug'

All i did was add a button to the activity_main.xml file, but the problem is that this error occurs even if I don't touch anything in the project.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: there's a button in the toolbar on top for syncing the project with Gradle, have you tried it ?

Comment: That produced exactly the same error... When i pressed run that is, the actual syncing worked fine. Just the run application produced the error

Comment: please share your build.gradle file

Comment: http://pastebin.com/p039a6WT

Comment: try changing the Gradle plugin version to 0.6.3 and make sure Gradle version is 1.8 in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: You can also track https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61633

Comment: Can you try building from the command line? From your project root directory, invoke `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace`. It should give you more error output and a Java/Groovy stack trace that will shed more light on the problem.